# Save data from `recvfrom()` to a structure to avoid extra bytes?

Tags: c++

I get the packages by upd and create the structure PSG. Then I save it to a vector and sort.At the end, I write all the byte data to a file. The problem is that the last packet is less than 1424 bytes. and because of this, extra bytes are written to the end of the file. How could I correctly save data from `recvfrom()` to a structure to avoid extra bytes?

```
#pragma pack(push, 1)
    struct PSG
    {
        uint64_t id;
        uint64_t size;
        uint32_t type;
        uint32_t count;
        uint8_t data[1400];
    };
    #pragma pack(pop)


PSG psg;
std::vector<PSG> psg_vector;
 while(1) {

        if ((bytesrecv = recvfrom(m_sock, &psg, 1424, 0, (sockaddr *) NULL, NULL)) < 0) {
            perror("recvfrom");
            close(m_sock);
            return -1;
        }
       psg_vector.push_back(psg);

       sort(psg_vector.begin(), psg_vector.end(), [](const auto &lhs, const 
            auto &rhs) {
            return lhs.count < rhs.count;
        });
       for (auto &a: psg_vector) {
           file.write(reinterpret_cast<const char *>(&a.data), sizeof(a.data));
}

}
```

Comment: Perhaps use something else than `sizeof(a.data)`, maybe `PSG::count`?

Comment: Instead of passing sizeof(a.data) to file.write(), calculate the actual number of bytes you want to write and pass that.

Comment: from the [manpage](https://linux.die.net/man/2/recvfrom): `recvfrom` returns "...the number of bytes received, or -1 if an error occurred. The return value will be 0 when the peer has performed an orderly shutdown.". Use `bytesrecv` to check for errors and to determine how many bytes to write to file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting the size of the packet read in `bytesrecv`, but then you're ignoring it and not using it.  Store it somewher and use it.  You could add it to your PSG object:

```
#pragma pack(push, 1)
    struct PSG
    {
        uint64_t id;
        uint64_t size;
        uint32_t type;
        uint32_t count;
        uint8_t data[1400];
        ssize_t size;
    };
    #pragma pack(pop)


PSG psg;
std::vector<PSG> psg_vector;
 while(1) {

        if ((psg.size = recvfrom(m_sock, &psg, 1424, 0, (sockaddr *) NULL, NULL)) < 0) {
            perror("recvfrom");
            close(m_sock);
            return -1;
        }
       psg_vector.push_back(psg);
```

Answer (score 0):

Example on linux sockets. You need this lines:

```
if (!length)  // Write entire buffer
   fileManager.WriteFile(data->buffer, BUFF_LENGTH);
else  // Write remain
{
   fileManager.WriteFile(data->buffer, length);
   break;
}
```

Full example:

```
struct Packet
{
     enum class TYPE
     {
        DEFAULT = 3,  // Default condition
        LAST_OF_FILE = 4,  // Last packet of file
        N_LAST_OF_FILE = 5,  // Not last packet of file
        LAST_IN_GROUP = 6,  // Last file in group of files, sent by client
        N_LAST_IN_GROUP = 7,  // Not last file in group of files, sent by client
        ANSWER = 8  // Answer
     };

    uint32_t length;
    TYPE type;
    char buffer[BUFF_LENGTH];

    void clear()
    {
        memset(this, 0, sizeof(Packet));
    }
};


bool ReceiveOnePacket(Packet* pack, int* socket)
{
    // summary quantity of received bytes
    uint32_t bytes = 0;

    while (bytes < sizeof(Packet))
    {
        // a tcp socket cannot give the entire packet as a whole, so we read it in parts.
        // We read with a shift and reduce the number of remaining bytes
        int len = recv(*socket, ((char*)pack) + bytes, sizeof(Packet) - bytes, 0);

        if (len <= 0)
            return false;

        bytes += len;
    }
    return true;
}

void ReceivingFiles(std::shared_ptr<int> socket, std::shared_ptr<Packet> data)
{
    data->clear();
    bool isLastFile = false;

    while (!isLastFile)  // Receiving set of files
    {
        // receiving filename of current file
        if (!ReceiveOnePacket(data.get(), socket.get()))
        {
            close(*socket);
            return;
        }

        // if current file is last then data->packetType == Packet::TYPE::LAST_IN_GROUP,
        // if file not last, data->packetType == Packet::TYPE::N_LAST_IN_GROUP
        isLastFile = data->type == Packet::TYPE::LAST_IN_GROUP;

        std::string metaData(data->buffer, data->length);

        fileManager.OpenFile(metaData);

        // Receiving one File
        while (true)
        {
            if (!ReceiveOnePacket(data.get(), socket.get()))
            {
                fileManager.DeleteFile();
                close(*socket);
                return;
            }

            uint32_t length = data->length;

            if (!length)  // Write entire buffer
                fileManager.WriteFile(data->buffer, BUFF_LENGTH);
            else  // Write remain
            {
                fileManager.WriteFile(data->buffer, length);
                break;
            }

        }  // End Receiving one file
    }
}
```